# IDesign AddDbContext with an interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a new asp.net core web application using Razor pages. I want to add my db context in the startup.cs file, but I am using something called IDesign.

My DbContext entity is in a project that I am not allowed to reference. I need to somehow add my context either at the accessor layer or something else. I'm not super familiar with how services work for .net core.

I have a solution set up like this:

1. Clients Project

   1. The project with the cshtml files, startupcs and all of that is here
   2. Can only reference managers and utilities projects
2. Managers Project

   1. Used for chaining calls to engines/accessors to accomplish tasks at a high level
   2. Used to make calls to accessors
   3. Can only reference accessors, engines, and utilities project
3. Engines Project

   1. Used for business logic
   2. Can only reference the accessors and utilities projects
4. Accessors Project

   1. resource accessors. Hits dbs/services.
   2. This is where my dbcontext class lives
   3. can't reference anything except for utilities
5. Utilities Project

   1. Used to store global classes and utility functions that apply to all projects
   2. Can't reference anything

My problem is that if my DbContext lives in the accessors project, how do I pass that up from the managers so that I can use it in the clients? Has anyone had experience with this before?

Just to reiterate, I know that I could easily reference accessors project in the clients project and use the dbcontext from there. My problem is that I want to avoid being able to reference accessors so that other people who are working with this code aren't able to see any accessors classes.

Comment: "how do I pass that up from the managers so that I can use it in the clients?" - why should your clients use DbContext? Your resource access encapsulates volatility of resource, today its Ef Core, tommorow a simple file. You should encapsulate that volatility, but you want to expose it to everyone, or am I missing smth...

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `DbContext` related classes in a new project without the parts of the "Accessors" project. It will be similar to the "Utilities" project, which can be used/referenced by all projects. This way your "Clients" project knows what a `DbContext` object is and how to use it, but it doesn't know how to get one (unless it has a connection string and connects to the database directly using the `DbContext` class). This would be the responsible of the "Managers" or "Accessors" project.

The references chain will look like this:

[image]

Comment: So you don't believe there is any good way to make the manager be able to pass a DBContext from an Accessor up to a client? 

I was kind've hoping that because the AddDbContext message takes a TContext that there might be a way... but TContext isn't an interface so probably not?

Comment: @AdamG When you move the `DBContext` class (and all the related classes) to such an new project "Database" you can reference this project instead, can use the `DBContext` class and cannot access the classes in "Accessors".

Comment: Why client should use DbContext class? That should be avoided, cause DbContext may change tommorow to anything else, you will be forced to change your code everywhere...(Ra, Managers, Clients)